# CSS - Responsive design for keeping an image inside a desktop-frame image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a list of screenshots. I want to display those inside a desktop-frame. I can achieve the effect easily with CSS but trying to make it responsive is giving me headaches.

My Html structure and style:

```
<style>
    .container {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .frame {
        list-style-type: none;
        background-image: url('http://www.hobbysubmarines.com/TV.png');
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 651px;
        height: 358px;
    }
    .frame li {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .screenshot {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        left: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="frame">
        <li><img class="screenshot" src="../img/screenshot1.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/faj2rfc8/1/  so you maybe get the idea. If you see the fiddle, it is just to put the cat inside the tv-frame. Making this responsive is my main issue.

Comment: Any fiddle or images for your problem may help us

Comment: I guess you forgot to close your `<style>`

Comment: You might want to look into `@media-queries`. An idea would be to look over what resolutions / devices are you targeting and kick in layout changes when you reach them on resize.

Answer (score 0):

I would size the background in 100%, and add a media query to reduce the height of the screenshots for smaller screens. I put a fiddle together for you:

```
    .container {
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .frame {
        background-image: url('http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg');
        background-size: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 651px;
        height: 358px;
    }
    .screenshot {
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        left: 5px;
        height: 100px;
    }

// mobile only
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .screenshot {
        height: 40px;
    }
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gg89qwon/1/